# I am trying to save this user edit to a data base but it's not working

Tags: laravel-5.1

My model:

```
static public function userEddit($request){

   $user = new self();
   $user->name = $request['name'];
   $user->email = $request['email'];
   $user->password = bcrypt($request['password']);
   $user->save();
  DB::insert('INSERT INTO users_role VALUES(' . $user->id .',5)');
}
```

My UserContorller

```
    public function postUser(PostUser $request){
    User::userEddit($request);
    return redirect('shop');
}
```

Comment: Does your users_role table only have 2 columns? If not you'll have to list the columns you're inserting into before the `VALUES()`.

Comment: users_role table have 2 colums.

Comment: I'm not sure why your code isn't working. But you should try doing this with the [attach method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships) as part of a [many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: Are you trying to insert user or edit user? `$user = new self();` creates a new user

Comment: $user = User::find($id);
       $user->name = $request['name'];
       $user->email = $request['email'];
       $user->password = bcrypt($request['password']);
       $user->save();                                      ******even this not working

Comment: i don't understand why it's not working, because in my crm i'm also have add\edit users, and it's working perfect, but here it's is for user that the user will be able to edit his profile , and it's not working